# Connect with facebook - ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am trying to develop a “connect with facebook” with ASP.NET 3.5 and have followed lots of articles but I am not able to get it working. Most of the developers who spoke about this matter end up referring to the below article: 
devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/

I followed that article, but the only thing I was able to get working was checking the authentication status of the current user:
devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/

However, trying to read users’ data gives me the following error all the time (although the same key was used in the previous successful test! - checking the authentication):

Invalid API key specified
The app you are trying to access does not exist or has been disabled.

The link to the 2 pages I developed are below, you may try them to see what I have done:
http://www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/connect.aspx (the connect method - works fine)
http://www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/bkonrad_1.aspx (reading users data - error)

I basically want users to click on the “connect with facebook” on my page to login using facebook and my code reads users’ info and save the users’ basic information to my database.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Checked your both pages
Your user data page gives below error.
FB.Event is undifined.

and also you dont have the refeence to the fb script above your code.

try adding these lines in your code above FB.Init

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Read my blog for deail facebook connect integration
http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/facebook-connect.html

Comment: Neelam, I added the lines you told me about but I still get the same error. How come my first page works fine and shows the Facebook popup page correctly and asks the user to login and allow permission, while the other one says that the App ID is wrong! On the other hand, I followed your article but did not get how it can help me in solving my problem! Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: hey..just cheked your http://www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/bkonrad_1.aspx page agan...the appID is missing in source code.

Comment: Neelam, the app ID is not missing! It reads a variable from my webconfig! The same code works fine for my other page!

Comment: hey,This is the code in your http://www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/connect.aspx page..........    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init("101578889945661", "xd_receiver.htm");
        //alert('101578889945661');
    </script>
and thisis the code in your  http://www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/bkonrad_1.aspx page......    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init("", "xd_receiver.htm");
    </script>....this page clealy is not getting appID.

Comment: Neelam, I hardcoded the app ID, and started getting "Stack Overflow" error on this line:     <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
What do you recommend?

Comment: you have reference to <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> just above the FB.Init code.So i think you can remove reference to ths script from your page header tag  <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Neelam, I removed that line, and now the "connect using facebook" button stopped showing! Check the new link: www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/bkonrad_1_A.aspx

Comment: hey...have uploaded an aspx page here with facebook connect https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0X_uz2m0NNPZGJkYzU4MjctNWQ3YS00ZjE0LTljNzEtNGFmZGVhNzZiNmEw&hl=en_US

Comment: Neelam, please let's not mix both topics, I am commenting on your blog over there, and that's where you posted your default.aspx to help me understand your code, but over here, my problem is a different one. I want to be able to read the user's basic information from code behind page. Implementing that is giving me the error I showed you.

Comment: I'm not mixing up these things.Right now you have problem in your facebook button.See in that code what you are missing.

Comment: Neelam, the code I have is taken from that article I posted earlier, anyways, it seems that the article is outdated! I have taken code from your page and done changes to that same page of mine, but now clicking on the button refreshes the page but does not do anything. What do you think? www.myifaworld.com/desktopModules/facebook/bkonrad_1_A.aspx

Comment: The code I followed in the mentioned article has dome facebook dlls, don't you think that I might want to replace those dlls? Are you using any dlls in your project?

Comment: That is just the code for logging in so the page wont do anything...if you want to show user data than you willhave to call different methods.Like in my page i added a code called FB.UI for page request.refer here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/ for all options on what data you cn get and how.

Comment: Neelam, the code I got from bknorad article are to read first/last names of the user from code behind, and the author says that it works fine. If you look at the link I mentioned in my question, you'll see the full code of aspx and .vb which - as author says - should be enough to work!

Comment: Hey..the code that u have in ur page logs a user in.thats it.If u want user data u have to call diff methods.Their r two ways to do tht.Javascript or graph api.the page i gave u has javascript code so the code behind doesnt do anything.the bknorad article u r talking abt might b using Graph api or some client library and does its processing in code behind.U can even combine graph api nd javascript thts ur call.